# How to get IP from hostname on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How do I get the IP from a given hostname on iOS?

I've tried Google but found nothing.

Comment: No, I want the IP of a hostname. Fx. I give the app the hostname Google.com and it returns the ip.

Comment: Can't you just ping the hostname and capture the responding IP?

Comment: Ok then [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567521/obtaining-a-server-ip-address-from-hostname)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450621/how-to-get-the-external-ip-in-objective-c is about determining the "external" IP address of a device behind a firewall, so this is **not a duplicate** of that question.

Comment: @user2062950, while that does give a reasonable answer, MartinR's answer below is preferable. getnameinfo() has replace gethostbyname().

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following code works with both IPv4 and IPv6. It uses `getaddrinfo()` to
retrieve a list of IP addresses for a host, and `getnameinfo()` to convert
each IP address into a string. (Error checking omitted for brevity.)

```
struct addrinfo hints;
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = PF_UNSPEC;        // PF_INET if you want only IPv4 addresses
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

struct addrinfo *addrs, *addr;

getaddrinfo("www.google.com", NULL, &hints, &addrs);
for (addr = addrs; addr; addr = addr->ai_next) {

    char host[NI_MAXHOST];
    getnameinfo(addr->ai_addr, addr->ai_addrlen, host, sizeof(host), NULL, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST);
    printf("%s\n", host);

}
freeaddrinfo(addrs);
```

Comment: Got this error: Definition of 'struct addrinfo' must be imported from module 'Darwin.POSIX.netdb' before it is required

Comment: @RoboForm: You have to add some include files. If you type "man getaddrinfo" on the command line you will see what include files are needed.